# What are some songs/music piece that I can use to practice Violin?

Tags: violin

I just started to learn violin. So far, I only know how to play "Ode to Joy" and also learning to play "Canon" in C.

Can you please suggest me some songs that are easy for beginner like me to practice on? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want music chosen and edited very carefully for learning, the [Suzuki Method](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0874871441) has a lot of pieces that are fun to play, nice to listen to, and will improve your ear and violin technique quite effectively.

Word of caution though, if Suzuki is your first exposure to music performance, you absolutely *must* balance it with something of a theoretical nature. Suzuki encourages you to learn by ear, which is great and all, but it leaves your sight reading and knowledge of harmony really shoddy.

Trust me -- not only is this conventional wisdom (Suzuki himself agrees), I made the mistake of neglecting non-Suzuki stuff, and I'm still in the process of trying to fill in the gaps.

I'd recommend learning a chordal instrument as well when you have time, such as piano or guitar.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good practice books out there that contain popular tunes. I recommend music targeted at beginner violinists because it will have written fingerings and focus on the positions and shifts that beginners need to learn first. Get some advice from a teacher or any musicians you know in your preferred genre of music. If you don't know anyone, I'd start with classical, because I suspect it has the largest selection for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few books such as the stepping stones and waggon wheel's series that contain lots of simple tunes to learn and play - I'd recommend investing in one or two of these. They also usually come in progressions, so as you work your way through the series they'll get increasingly challenging.

Answer (score 1):

As a violin and fiddle teacher (since 1986), my best answer is to ask your teacher.  If you do not have a teacher, why don't you?  Seriously with this day and age you can find most teachers online if you don't have one nearby.

Having said that, I suggest you find a copy of the Fiddler's Fakebook.  If you're looking specifically for dance music (jigs, reels, hornpipes and the like), then you'll love the Portland Collection (there are 2.  start with the blue one), and the Waltz Books (there are 4, start with the pink one).  This is assuming you can read music.

If you can't read music, refer to my first paragraph on finding a teacher!  Of course you can learn to read music on your own also, but it is harder than having someone help you and give you goals.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking any song you like and play a vocal line from it. Just play the same notes that vocalist sings with his/her voice. This is:

1. Very simple in most cases
2. Very fun, since vocal melodies are easy recognizable.

You can transcribe vocal melodies by ear, which would be the best option, or find some guitar pro tabs on the net - many of them have the vocal lines layed out note by note.